# Is there a way to hide the system/navigation bar in Adobe AIR apps for Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, uinavigationbar

I'd like to extend the discussion regarding hiding of the system/navigation bar at the bottom of the screen on Android Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0 and up) tablet devices, i am using Adobe AIR sdk to develop applications in Adobe Flash builder.

There's already a thread about hiding the bar on Honeycomb devices. My clients, however, will be using the newest Ice Cream Sandwich devices and are very keen on hiding the bar at the bottom the screen. Their application is not for regular consumer use and it's very important for them to take over the whole screen to provide their experience. How possible is it to hide this bar ?

By using this code i can hide in Android applications

```
private static int getSystemUiFlags() {
            return View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }
```

but, i am looking for equivalent `Action script` flags to hide navigation bar in Adobe AIR apps for Android.

Comment: check out that ANE https://github.com/mesmotronic/air-fullscreen-ane